Problem loading a serveer certificate in .p12 format with a AES-256-CBC
I getting this error when trying to load a .p12 certificate in .Net 7:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The specified network password is not correct.'

With this code:
var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certs.Import(certBytes, password);

And after a some mailing with the support of the service provider i try to connect to with the server certificate i got a new certificate that works fine.
They saying that the first one giving "network password is not correct" was created in new version of OpenSSL with AES-256-CBC and the new one working is done with with OpenSSL 1.1.1 and pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC but both is created from same original pem and key files.
Anyone having a idea why i can not load in .Net 7 the certificate created with new OpenSSL and AES-256-CBC ?

Are you sure that the password for the first certificate is correct, i.e. have you tried to check the certificate with this password using another code/tool (e.g. OpenSSL)?

If the certificate/password is OK, .NET probably does not actually support the algorithm. BC/BouncyCastle might then be an option.

Are you using something older than Windows 10?  Windows has support for AES now, but it was added "recently" (somewhere during Windows 10)

@Topaco I can install it to Windows certificate store with the password i got from the service provider but when .Net 7 try to load it its getting the network password is wrong.

@bartonjs On the dev machine i have WIndows Server 2016 Standard but i think its more the .Net version the problem is with.

Windows support for AES-256-CBC in a PFX seems to have been added in Windows 10-1709.  So it will fail if you are using Windows Server 2016 (as only the "1607" variant of 2016 is still in support).
Until 2023, .NET on Windows never looked at a PFX, just sent it down to the OS; but in the cases where .NET does look at the PFX it supports the modern algorithms, regardless of the Windows version. (Depending on the specific .NET version and the specific PFX, that might make your PFX accidentally work Windows Server 2016... but, in general, it won't)
